# Select records having one of two possibilities in sql server query

Tags: sql-server

Thank you in advance for your help, here I go:

I have a table like this:

```
|Content | Syndication_type | Syndication_publication|
------------------------------------------------------
|    A   |          1       |              1         |
|    A   |          2       |              1         | 
|    B   |          2       |              1         |
|    C   |          1       |              0         |
|    D   |          1       |              0         |
|    D   |          2       |              1         |
|    E   |          2       |              1         |
|    F   |          1       |              1         |
```

I need to get Content which has only one `syndication_type` with `syndication_publication = 1`.

For example, if I choose `syndication_type = 2`, I have to obtain `Content = B`, `Content = D`, and `Content = E`, since they have only `syndication_publication = 1` for `syndication_type = 2`.

`Content = 2` is not the case since it has both `Syndication_type = 1` and `Syndication_type = 2` with `Syndication_publication = 1`, whereas, `Content = D` is ok, since it has only `Syndication_publication = 2` with `Syndication_publication = 1`.

I hope I explained my purpose... :)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please show us your query so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT  [Content]
FROM    MyTable mt
WHERE   [Syndication_type] = 2
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    MyTable mt2
            WHERE   mt2.[Content] = mt.[Content]
                    AND mt2.Syndication_publication = 1
                    AND mt2.Syndication_type <> mt.Syndication_type 
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution works if I add [Syndication_publication = 1] close after first WHERE [Syndication_type] = 2  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT Content 
FROM yourtable
WHERE Syndication_type = 1 -- your conditions
GROUP BY Content, Syndication_type 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Syndication_publication) = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried, but also Content = A has been getting out... and it is not correct, since A has both syndication_type = 1 and syndication_type = 2 with syndication_publication = 1, therefore, A has to be excluded from the result. Thank you